# Error while importing NativeMobileSDKBridgePackage when using amazon chime integration into existing react-native project

Tags: react-native, amazon-chime

While following the documentation provided on [github](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-react-native-demo) to integrate chime into existing react-native project, this line

```
packages.add(new NativeMobileSDKBridgePackage());
```

throwing error. Even after adding import as

```
package com.abc.mainFolder;

import com.abc.mainFolder.NativeMobileSDKBridgePackage;
```

`NativeMobileSDKBridgePackage.kt` file is present in the above import path.

Comment: try to run that github demo first:), rn i'm working on same with but in Flutter.